# Assert in call to wxDataViewListCtrl::EditItem in a second wxDataViewListCtrl

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm getting the following assert when wxDataViewListCtrl::EditItem is called a second time.

```
../../src/wxwidgets/src/gtk/dataview.cpp(221): assert "gtk_tree_selection_get_select_function(m_selection) == func" failed in CheckCurrentSelectionFunc(): selection function has changed unexpectedly, review this code!
```

See the code at https://pastebin.com/TEtK5C7S

To reproduce: choose Menu, Show Dialog. In the dialog choose Add and then Close.
Again choose Menu, Show Dialog and in the dialog choose Add.

Ubuntu 17.04 x64, tested with master, WX_3_0_BRANCH and WX_3_0_3_BRANCH
Configured with --enable-debug --enable-unicode --disable-universal
Default config is gtk2-unicode-3.0

Edit: After further testing I found that assert occurs in a call to EditItem in a second wxDataViewListCtrl.

Comment: can you try to reproduce it in the 'dataview' sample?

Comment: Not sure but maybe you can change `mapping.push_back("");` to `mapping.push_back(wxVariant(""));`

Comment: @igor I tried and found easier to have a standalone application showing the problem.

Comment: @macroland no difference. What was the rationale behind this change?

Comment: @josuegomes, does this mean you were not able to reproduce it? Moreover, I seriously doubt that you standalone app will be looked at. Core devs are busy people and the best way for them to look at the bug is to try to reproduce in the sample and submit the patch to it. They do know the code in the samples inside out and can easily test the newly submitted code.

Comment: @igor I think my standalone application qualifies as https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @josuegomes, correct. but you trac submission does not. (Well let me rephrase - it is, but it is much-much better to submit either a patch to the sample or an explanation on how to reproduce the bug).

Comment: @igor thank you. I don't think I can reproduce it in the 'dataview' sample but I can do it in the 'minimal'

Comment: @josuegomes, what prevents you from making the same changes in the dataview sample? Or - what is different between your code and the DV sample code? I believe the DV sample already have a button for adding a row. Did you try that?

Comment: @josuegomes, also it would be nice to have a complete backtrace of the assert.

Comment: @igor thank you, I'll attach a backtrace

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in wxWidgets, thanks for reporting it.

Fixed now in both [master](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/81d9952dfe4585c9d2c8a537cf15d24167fa9992) and [3.0](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/28aee1bc9e0b455a3427bc1cfc4f1ba34e272e26) branch and so will work in 3.0.4 and 3.1.1 when they're released.